# Distance, Speed and Time Word Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The word problem:

Mark walks 2000 feet west and 600 feet north of his starting position. In the side walk the speed is 6 ft/sec and 4 ft/sec through the grass. How far should he walk on the sidewalk before moving onto the grass to arrive to his destination in 7 min 30 sec?

I tried this

x/6 + (2600-x)/4 = 2600/450

but I end up with 0 what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you are walking along the hypotenuse of a right triangle if you are on the grass (the sidewalk stretches to the west, while everything to the north of the sidewalk is grass?). So we should get something like:
$$
\frac{x}{6} + \frac{\sqrt{600^2 + (2000 - x)^2}}{4} = 450
$$
Solving, we get that:
$$
x = 1200, 1680
$$

---

As an aside, in calculus you would be asked to minimize the left hand side. It turns out that the optimal transition point from sidewalk to grass occurs when $x \approx 1463.3437$.

Comment: I don't understand the second part how did you get the 1463.3437?

Comment: Don't worry about the second part. That's something you learn when you take calculus; you would have to compute a derivative, and set it to be equal to zero.